# Closure is not constructible with

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I am practicing Swift and I have the following code:

```
import Foundation

@objc class Model {

typealias completionBlock = (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void

func saveEmailAccount(email: String, password: String, mailServer: String, mailPort: Int, completionHandler: completionBlock) -> Void {
    let httpPOSTBody = ["email" : email, "password" : password, "mailServer" : mailServer, "mailPort" : mailPort]
    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(httpPOSTBody, options: nil, error: nil)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    session.dataTaskWithURL(urlRequest.URL!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        completionBlock(data, error)
    })
  }
}
```

But I am getting **"completionBlock is not constructible with '(NSData!, NSError!)'**. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to invoke `completionHandler` with the typo `completionBlock`    Change the block invocation from:

```
completionBlock(data, error)
```

to:

```
completionHandler(data, error)
```

One reason why Apple suggests (and I concur) that type names should start with caps and variable names with lower case.

The other problem is that by defining the type alias as:

```
typealias completionBlock = (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void
```

You are specifying that the completion block should be defined and called with named parameters:

```
completionHandler(data:data, error:error)
```

Or, change the type alias to:

```
typealias completionBlock = (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void
```

Which would be more inline with the norms I've seen.